# Including Method Missing for Blocks with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I do this call to an API, I get a Hash back. I'm sneakily converting that Hash to have some of the same properties of an object, namely methods :D.

Instead of `item['name']` I can do `item.name`. Awesome!

Here's some of the code with Twitter as the proxy:

```
module Twitter
  class Base
    include HTTParty

    base_uri 'api.twitter.com'
    format :json
    default_params api_password: ENV['TWITTER_PASSWORD']
  end

  refine Base::Hash do
    def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
      self.has_key?(method.to_s)? self[method.to_s] : super
    end

    def respond_to?(method, include_private = false)
      self.has_key?(method.to_s) || super
    end
  end
end
```

Then I can make a Tweet model:

```
module Twitter
  class Tweet < Twitter::Base
    class << self
      def all
        get '/v1.1/tweet'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

That's cool. This example won't work. Its a really dumbed down version of what I'm really trying to do: Make a Hash act like an Object. Now that you know what's going on, lets show you the problem:

What works:

```
tweet.first['text']
# => 'this is the text from a hash.'

tweet.first.text
# => 'this is the text from a hash.'

tweet.first.respond_to? text
# => true
```

What doesn't work:

```
tweet.map(&:text)
# => #<NoMethodError: undefined method `text' for #<Hash:0x007fb1322a1468>>

tweet.sort_by(&:created_at)
# => #<NoMethodError: undefined method `created_at' for #<Hash:0x007fb1322a1468>>
```

My metaprogramming brain is fried. I've gotten this far. Does anyone have any ideas on anything else I can do to get blocks to work with methods such as `#map` and `#sort_by`?

**Update**:

I decided to find out how `#sort_by` is failing. Still not able to answer this, but this is my investigation:

```
tweet = Twitter::Tweet.all
tweet.sort_by(&:created_at)
# => undefined method `created_at' for #<Hash:0x007f9ae28ccfb0>
```

That adds some context. Now onto finding out what `tweet` is in the context of `#sort_by`:

```
tweet.method(:sort_by)
# => #<Method: Array(Enumerable)#sort_by>
```

And now we have more context.

**Solved**:

Considering it was the `Array` that was the bottleneck, I decided to go with this implementation:

```
def all
  respone = get '/v1/tweet.json'
  array = []

  response.each do |res|
    array << RecursiveOpenStruct.new(res)
  end

  array
end
```

But this was *not* going to scale well with the application. I was going to use `after_action`, but discovered that I needed a table. I didn't even go down the [tableless model path](http://railscasts.com/episodes/193-tableless-model).

I therefore decided to just reopen `HTTParty` and redo `#get` for my own needs. First step was to update the Gemfile to ensure I'm sitting at a single version and then I did this:

```
module HTTParty
  module ClassMethods
    def get(path, options={}, &block)
      response = perform_request Net::HTTP::Get, path, options, &block
      methodize_array response if response.is_a? Array
    end

    def methodize_array(response)
      array = []

      response.each do |res|
        array << RecursiveOpenStruct.new(res)
      end

      array
    end
  end
end
```

And now I can call methods on hash through an API that will be scalable and effecient. If anyone has any comments, please let me know.

Comment: Could it be that _one_ of the elements does not have the key `'text'`?

Comment: Nope. It was easy to figure that one out... But the hash that is returned will have the key; which is `text` in this example.

Comment: What is `tweet.first.class`? Is it `::Hash`?

Comment: Yes: `tweet.first.class # => Hash`

Comment: But: `tweet.class # => HTTParty::Response` and `tweet.is_a? Array # => true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an openstruct, its builtin:

```
# require 'ostruct'

hash = {a: 1, b: 2}
object = OpenStruct.new hash
object.a # => 1
```

If you have a nested structure, [use a gem like this](https://github.com/aetherknight/recursive-open-struct), or [do it yourself like this](http://andreapavoni.com/blog/2013/4/create-recursive-openstruct-from-a-ruby-hash/#.U32u9liSzR1)

You'll then be able to use all your `sort_by` or `map` methods and will certainly gain in performance.

Comment: No. Its not dynamic enough. Limited use case.

Comment: Let me doubt it, I always use it, and didnt find limited use cases... (in case you're wondering, I'm not the one downvoting)

Comment: Can you please update your answer on how I could implement it within `Twitter::Base` and how you would deal with Hash within a Hash within a Hash? Or rather: make it convert all keys, no matter the depth, into objects. OpenStruct was giving me this head ache.

Comment: Read my answer :) for nested structures, you can use a gem or build your own solution

Comment: I am curious, though. How can an object successfully handle `method_missing` and fail when passed to `map`. http://pastie.org/9198317 Something non-compliant is going on there (for example, their `map` is not `Enumerable#map` or something like that)

Comment: I decided to do some investigating. `tweet.method(:sort_by)` presents me with `#<Method: Array(Enumerable)#sort_by>`.

Comment: I've updated my answer @SergioTulentsev. You now have some context on what is happening here.

Comment: `RecursiveOpenStruct` worked. See my update above on how it was implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try [Hashie](https://github.com/intridea/hashie) and include the `MethodAccess` extension in your Twitter result. Here's the example from the docs:

```
class MyHash < Hash
  include Hashie::Extensions::MethodAccess
end
h = MyHash.new
h.abc = 'def'
h.abc  # => 'def'
h.abc? # => true
```